# Android Studio 2020.3.1 Canary 5 problems: "lateinit property variantName" and more

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

I have am running Canary Android Studio on both a desktop and laptop, working with Compose.

The since moving to Canary 5 I have problems on both, both were fine on Canary 4.

On the Desktop, build of even the automatic compose empty activity project (and all others) die immediately with "lateinit property variantName has not been intialised"
[image]
This problems blocks being able to develop. Even a resinstall got nowhere, despite the problem happening even with a newly created empty activity project.  Possibly there is some config on that machine that did not survive the update. Any thoughts appreciated.

On the laptop, project was building, but now produces the same error..

Comment: I also have this problem, but only when I use the `build` gradle task.  If I use `assemble`, it builds successfully, but of course does not run tests.

Update: Since `build` performs `assemble`, `lint` and `test`, I checked them individually, and it's the `lint` task that causes the error.